# Update query does not update few rows

Tags: mysql, sql

With the following table:

```
"id"    "type"  "parent"    "country"   "votes" "perCent"
"1"     "1"     "0"         "US"        "0"     "0"//Appears as 0, should be 12
"2"     "2"     "1"         "US"        "0"     "0"//Appears as 0, should be 8
"3"     "3"     "2"         "US"        "4"     "0"
"7"     "3"     "2"         "US"        "4"     "0"
"19"    "3"     "1"         "US"        "4"     "0"
"4183"  "10"    "3"         "US"        "2"     "0"
"4184"  "10"    "3"         "US"        "2"     "0"
"4185"  "10"    "7"         "US"        "2"     "0"
"4186"  "10"    "7"         "US"        "2"     "0"
"4187"  "10"    "19"        "US"        "2"     "0"
"4188"  "10"    "19"        "US"        "2"     "0"
```

Why does row id 1 and row id 2 appear as 0 when i run the following query to update the totals?

```
UPDATE  likesd a
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  parent, country, SUM(votes) totalVotes
            FROM    likesd
            GROUP   BY parent
        ) b ON a.id = b.parent and a.country = b.country
SET     a.votes = b.totalVotes; select * from likesd;
```

When I do:

```
SELECT  parent, country, SUM(votes) totalVotes
            FROM    likesd
            GROUP   BY parent;
```

I can see all the rows in the result, but the top two don't update.

Am I going wrong with my sql? How do i set this right? Also, do u see any problems in the sql i'm using?

Comment: have you tested your above query ,,,I think there are error in inner query. and please provide good information about your question

Comment: Yes I've tested. It works fine, except the last two rows.

Comment: @jmenezes Note that choices with regard to recursion include constructing a sproc, handling the logic at the application level, or switching from an edge list/adjacency model to, for instance, a nested set.<-- In this instance, I think this would be my preference. Remember, the content and the hierarchical model can (and probably should) be split into separate entities.

Answer (score 1):

you should put country also in group by clause as you are checking country also while updating.

```
UPDATE  likesd a
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  parent, country, SUM(votes) totalVotes
            FROM    likesd
            GROUP   BY parent, country
        ) b ON a.id = b.parent and a.country = b.country
SET     a.votes = b.totalVotes; select * from likesd;
```

**EDIT**
you can try following update statement in case of some unexpected result -

```
UPDATE Likesd a
   SET Voltes = (SELECT SUM(Votes)
                   FROM Likesd b
                  WHERE b.PARENT = a.Id
                    AND b.Country = a.Country)
```

Comment: @jmenezes you can use the second query for update you table.
i have just udpated and tested this query.